# custom android keyboard key label two lines

Tags: android, keyboard

in android custom keyboard I want to put key for "select all" and I dont want the two word of "select all" to be next to other in the same line, I want the "all" to be under the "select" in the same key, any help ?
this is the current code:

```
 <Key android:codes="-2000" android:keyLabel="select all"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<Key android:codes="-2000" android:keyLabel="select \n \t \t \t \t all`"/>
```

Comment: for further positioning of "all" change increment or decrement number of "\t"

Comment: thank you for replying, the "all" didnt appear, kindly view the image : http://www4.0zz0.com/2017/08/18/12/904904917.png

Comment: <string name="anything">select \n \t \t \t all</string>

Comment: Now reference this "anything" in your <Key android:codes="-2000" android:keyLabel="@string/anything"/>

Comment: thank you for your reply, but the problem still exist kindly view the pictures: 1- http://www13.0zz0.com/2017/08/18/14/313558453.png  2- http://www13.0zz0.com/2017/08/18/14/568178250.png  3- http://www13.0zz0.com/2017/08/18/14/278003195.jpg

Comment: You did everything correct. It should work. IDK whats happenig